# Why resource bundle is not loaded in java backed webscript

Tags: java, alfresco, spring-surf

I have a webscript defined as following:

- mywebscript.get.desc.xml
- mywebscript.get.properties
- mywebscript.get.json.ftl

This webscript is backed by a java controller like this:

```
<bean id="webscript.mypackage.mywebscript.get"
    class="javapackage.MyWebscriptGet" parent="webscript">
    <property name="serviceRegistry" ref="ServiceRegistry" />
    <property name="messageService" ref="messageService" />
</bean>
```

I can't retrieve in java code some properties defined in "mywebscript.get.properties",
I tried to use the `messageService` and `I18nUtil.getMessage`, but it seems that other properties are loaded, but the ones that i need are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resources in the `webscriptname.get.properties` files aren't available via the Message Service or I18NUtil. The latter two are globally scoped, while the webscript properties are specific to just that WebScript. To get them, you need to work with the WebScript definition.

In Java, that means doing something like:

```
protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req,
      Status status, Cache cache) 
{
   Map<String, String> templateVars = req.getServiceMatch().getTemplateVars();
   WebScript webscript = req.getServiceMatch().getWebScript();
   ResourceBundle webscriptRB = webscript.getResources();

   ....
}
```

From the `WebScriptRequest` get the `Match`, from there get the `WebScript`, and that will give you the webscript specific properties as a `ResourceBundle`